# Removing cell padding (email purposes)

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm asking why there's 1px of padding in the cells in the following code:

```html
     <table style="border: 1px solid #B0B0B0; width: 900px; height: 196px;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2 style="vertical-align: top;">
                <img src="http://ayudawp.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/imagen.jpg" alt="imagen" style="height:193px; width:285px;">
            </td>
            <td colspan=2 style="text-align: center;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna $
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                20e
            </td>
            <td>
                -60 %
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the image to be without top and left `padding`. And I can't use the `padding` attribute. Reading on CSS `table` specs, I read that extra `padding` is added if there are cells of different `height`s on a row, but even forcing each cell to have the same `height` doesn't fix that.

Comment: What do you mean by _"And I can't use the padding attribute"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on  what you said

> And I can't use the `padding` attribute

This seems to me that you are using this code for Email purposes.

So, here is a possible solution, by using the old `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` properties for `table` (plus I added `display:block`to your `img` to fix the gap caused by `img` being an inline element)

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #B0B0B0; width: 900px; height: 196px;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://ayudawp.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/imagen.jpg" alt="imagen" style="height:193px; width:285px;display:block" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20e</td>
        <td>-60 %</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If this is **not** for email purposes, do not use `cellpadding` nor `cellspacing` since they are deprecated, thus you have to use CSS atributes instead, like `padding`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, is for email purposes. I know maybe it's asking too much, but can you give me any link that teaches me something about email markup? Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help, if you think this answer was helpful, feel free to mark as accepted for future readers. Regarding your question, there are a lot of good tutorials that might help you on your path. [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is a good one. and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22613894/3448527) is a answer of mine with links about emails as well.
Based on your current code I would suggest you to make some changes if you would be keen to that.

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vo62ayuk/) to be cross-client as possible. if you like i can add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers have an internal stylesheet which defines the default styles for that browser.

In my case, Firefox has ([see it in the source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css#471))

```css
td {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

You can remove it with

```css
td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid #B0B0B0; width: 900px; height: 196px;border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 style="vertical-align: top;">
      <img src="http://ayudawp.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/imagen.jpg" alt="imagen" style="height:193px; width:285px;">
    </td>
    <td colspan=2 style="text-align: center;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna $
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      20e
    </td>
    <td>
      -60 %
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to just add `* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}` at top of each css file instead of having to deal with overriding default padding and margin values everywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/50cg5fyj/